# JSON construction for use in angular

Tags: json, angularjs

I am constructing a calendar with angular. What would be the best way to construct the JSON to be able to use the months for the sidebar and filter by months for the events displayed?

Is there a more flexible way to set up the schema than I currently have? Right now I would have to define a new schema for each month. Here is a link to end webpage view I am working with http://secret-hollows-7338.herokuapp.com/events.

```
var mongoose  = require('mongoose');
var Schema    = mongoose.Schema;

var CalendarSchema   = new Schema({

August: [
  {
    day: String,
    title: String,
    summary: String,
    description: String
  }
      ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('CalendarData',  CalendarSchema);
```

my controller

```
  $scope.calendar = [];

  CAL.API.query(function(results) {
        $scope.calendar = results;
    });
```

my view

```
<div class="events" ng-repeat="cal in calendar[0].August">
  <a href="/events/{{cal.day}}">
  <article class="eventslist">
   <div class="numberedDate">
   <h3>{{cal.day}}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="calInfo">
     <h5>{{cal.title}}</h5>
     <p>{{cal.summary}}&nbsp;<a>more</p>
     </div>
     </article>
     </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are probably several ways to approach this.

The way I see it would be to only create an event model :

```
var EventSchema   = new Schema({
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    title: String,
    summary: String,
    description: String
});
```

This way you store day/month/year/hour data directly into your events and you have much more flexibility for sorting, filtering and all sorts of usage.